# How to unit test reduxsauce?

Tags: redux, react-redux, jestjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

I am using reduxsauce library for redux store, and I want to unit test a single redux store in it. 
The redux file:

```js
import { createReducer, createActions } from 'reduxsauce'
import Immutable from 'seamless-immutable'

/* ------------- Types and Action Creators ------------- */

const { Types, Creators } = createActions({
  getLanguage: [],
  setLanguage: ['language']
})

export const LanguageTypes = Types
export default Creators

/* ------------- Initial State ------------- */

export const INITIAL_STATE = Immutable({
  language: "en"
})

/* ------------- Reducers ------------- */


export const getLanguage = (state: Object, {}: Object) => {
    return state.merge({})
}

export const setLanguage = (state: Object, { language }: Object) => {
    return state.merge({ language })
}

/* ------------- Hookup Reducers To Types ------------- */

export const reducer = createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
  [Types.SET_LANGUAGE]: setLanguage,
  [Types.GET_LANGUAGE]: getLanguage,
})
```

The test:

```js
import * as actions from '../../../redux/LanguageRedux'
import * as types from '../../../redux/LanguageRedux'

describe('Language redux ', () => {
  it('should have default language ', () => {
    expect(actions.INITIAL_STATE.language).toEqual("en")
  }),
  it('should be able to set the language', () => {
    // I know the calls below are not tests but still its relevant with the error
    actions.getLanguage()
    actions.setLanguage()
  })
})
```

Error:

```js
● Language redux  › should be able to set the language

    TypeError: Cannot destructure 'undefined' or 'null'.

      21 |
      22 |
    > 23 | export const getLanguage = (state: Object, {}: Object) => {
         |                            ^
      24 |     return state.merge({})
      25 | }
      26 |

      at Object.getLanguage (src/redux/LanguageRedux.js:23:28)
      at Object.getLanguage (src/__tests__/src/redux/LanguageRedux.js:9:13)
```

Now, I have the store configured in a different file but reducers is combined in a different file:

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import configureStore from './CreateStore'

import rootSaga from '../sagas'

export default () => {
    /* ------------- Assemble The Reducers ------------- */
    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
        language: require('./LanguageRedux').reducer
    })

    return configureStore(rootReducer, rootSaga)
}
```

Any one has a clue as to how could I test the redux actions etc. With normal redux I could find many articles but with reduxsauce library I cant seem to find anything. Any clues please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### What is being tested

`LanguageRedux.js` has the following exports:

- `LanguageTypes` - a map of the action types
- `Creators` - a map of the action creators
- `INITIAL_STATE` - the initial state of the app
- `getLanguage` and `setLanguage` - the reducer functions
- `reducer` - the redux reducer

I recommend importing everything with the expected identifiers like this:

```js
import Creators, {
  LanguageTypes,
  INITIAL_STATE,
  getLanguage,
  setLanguage,
  reducer
 } from '../../../redux/LanguageRedux';
```

**Note**: It looks like the `getLanguage` action is unnecessary since it does nothing to the state (if the app is getting the language it should just read it from the state), but I'll leave it in there since it is in the question code.

---

### LanguageTypes

`LanguageTypes` is just a map of the action types to their associated string value:

```js
it('should export the expected action types', () => {
  expect(LanguageTypes).toEqual({
    GET_LANGUAGE: 'GET_LANGUAGE',
    SET_LANGUAGE: 'SET_LANGUAGE'
  });  // Success!
});
```

---

### Creators

`Creators` is a map of the action creators.

Each action creator is a pure function that generates an action object based on the parameters given:

```js
describe('Creators', () => {

  describe('getLanguage', () => {

    it('should return the expected action', () => {
      expect(Creators.getLanguage()).toEqual({
        type: LanguageTypes.GET_LANGUAGE
      });
    });

    it('should ignore extra args', () => {
      expect(Creators.getLanguage('extra arg')).toEqual({
        type: LanguageTypes.GET_LANGUAGE
      });
    });

  });

  describe('setLanguage', () => {

    it('should return the expected action when passed nothing', () => {
      expect(Creators.setLanguage()).toEqual({
        type: LanguageTypes.SET_LANGUAGE
      });  // Success!
    });

    it('should return the expected action when passed a language', () => {
      expect(Creators.setLanguage('en')).toEqual({
        type: LanguageTypes.SET_LANGUAGE,
        language: 'en'
      });  // Success!
    });

    it('should ignore extra args', () => {
      expect(Creators.setLanguage('es', 'extra arg')).toEqual({
        type: LanguageTypes.SET_LANGUAGE,
        language: 'es'
      });  // Success!
    });

  });

});
```

---

### INITIAL_STATE

`INITIAL_STATE` is simply the initial state object the app starts with:

```js
it('should set the initial state ', () => {
  expect(INITIAL_STATE).toEqual({ language: "en" });  // Success!
});
```

---

### Reducer functions

`getLanguage` and `setLanguage` are reducer functions, meaning they are pure functions that return a new state based on the existing state and action they are given:

```js
describe('reducers', () => {

  describe('getLanguage', () => {

    it('should do nothing (probably should not be an action)', () => {
      expect(getLanguage(INITIAL_STATE, {})).toEqual(INITIAL_STATE);  // Success!
    });

    it('should ignore extra args', () => {
      expect(getLanguage(INITIAL_STATE, { extra: 'arg' })).toEqual(INITIAL_STATE);  // Success!
    });

  });

  describe('setLanguage', () => {

    it('should set the language', () => {
      expect(setLanguage(INITIAL_STATE, { language: 'es' })).toEqual({
        language: 'es'
      });  // Success!
    });

    it('should ignore extra args', () => {
      expect(setLanguage(INITIAL_STATE, { language: 'fr', extra: 'arg' })).toEqual({
        language: 'fr'
      });  // Success!
    });

  });

});
```

Note that testing reducer functions with `reduxsauce` is even easier than testing standard `redux` reducers since they will **only** be called for actions they are designed to handle.

---

### reducer

`reducer` is the redux reducer and its job is to route actions to the corresponding reducer function and return the resulting state:

```js
describe('reducer', () => {

  it('should return initial state if passed nothing', () => {
    expect(reducer()).toEqual(INITIAL_STATE);  // Success!
  });

  it('should route GET_LANGUAGE to getLanguage', () => {
    expect(reducer(INITIAL_STATE, Creators.getLanguage())).toEqual(INITIAL_STATE);  // Success!
  });

  it('should route SET_LANGUAGE to setLanguage', () => {
    expect(reducer(Immutable({ language: 'es' }), Creators.setLanguage('fr'))).toEqual({
      language: 'fr'
    });  // Success!
  });

});
```

**Note**: there are a few different ways that `reducer` can be tested.  The above approach passes the state and actions all the way through the reducer functions.  It is thorough, but also has a lot of overlap with the reducer function tests above.

The most basic alternative is to spy on `createReducer` and simply verify that it was called with the expected `INITIAL_STATE` and mapping object.

The approach halfway between that and the full approach above is to mock the reducer functions, pass `reducer` various actions, and verify that the correct reducer function was called.  This is probably the **ideal** approach but it is difficult to implement the way the code is currently written since `createReducer` runs as soon as the code is imported and captures references to the local functions `setLanguage` and `getLanguage`.  If you wanted to use this approach then the easiest way to do it would be to move `reducer` to its own module so you could mock the reducer functions *before* importing `reducer` into your test code.

Comment: Thanks for the help here. I removed getLanguage as your point is valid there, but still not sure how mocking would work as ideal approach here as I am still noob to React testing.