# How to get 100% test coverage using reduxsauce

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs

I'm trying to test a React application with Redux (`react-redux` + `reduxsauce`) using Jest.
I implemented the following approach:

```
import { createActions, createReducer } from "reduxsauce";

/**
* Action types & creators
*/
export const { Types, Creators } = createActions({
    addSample: ["text"],
    removeSample: ["id"]
});

/**
* Handlers
*/
export const INITIAL_STATE = [];
export function add(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    return [...state, { id: Math.random(), text: action.text }];
}
export function remove(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    return state.filter(sample => sample.id !== action.id);
}

/**
* Reducer
*/
export default createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
    [Types.ADD_SAMPLE]: add,
    [Types.REMOVE_SAMPLE]: remove
});
```

This implementation allows me to use Redux storage between components.
However, in the test I can't reach the 100% coverage, cuz only in the criterion of Branch I am coverage 0% (in the anothers criteria I reach 100% - Statements, Functions, Lines);
On feedback of the Coverage it is stated that on lines 16 and 20 I am not performing tests, on declarations of the Handlers `add()` and `remove()`.

I guess internally `reduxsauce` implements Reducer with some `switch case`, but I have no idea how I can testing this part of a way allow the test coverage criteria

Comment: Can you update your question to include your test code?  It's hard to tell why your test isn't getting complete code coverage without seeing it.  In the meantime my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55321808/10149510) talks about how to test reduxsauce and might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I'll edit my question and adding more detail. However, I also reached the possible solution to my question.

Comment: Dude, I've been thinking about it, I won't edit the question, because my problem can be solved just looking at the code snippets that I wrote. Well, I'll answer and hope that it's enough to help the community. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look at this section and it will be clear why the problem (in this case, not reach 100% coverage in the Branchs criterion).

```
/* ... */ add(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) { /* ... */
/* ... */ remove(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) { /* ... */
```

We could read this syntax as follows:

The declaration of `function add ()`, has the following condition

- if you pass a value in the first parameter, assume that `state` will have this value in the function scope;
- if not passed a value (or if this passed value is `undefined`), assume that`state` will have the value set to `INITIAL_STATE` in the function scope;

[Read more about this syntax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) ]

Because of this condition declared , it is necessary to test both possibilities for the test has 100% coverage in the Branch criteria.

e.g.:

```
it("should return INITIAL_STATE when passed undefined on parameter and sometingh on action",
 () => {
    expect(setCurrent(undefined, action)).toBe(INITIAL_STATE);
 }
);

it("should return 'test' when passed 'test' on parameter and sometingh on action", 
  () => {
    expect(setCurrent("test", action)).toBe('test');
  }
);
```